# Ecto / Elixir: Return first child of a nested association

Tags: sql, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have an Ecto query that's almost there but not quite!

It returns all Messages associated with the given Chats - but I'd like to only return the first Message from each Chat.

I've tried playing around with subqueries and fragments, but can't seem to get it down right.

```
Repo.one!(
  from(
    p in Post,
    where: p.id == ^id,
    join: c in assoc(p, :chats),
    join: y in assoc(c, :messages),
    preload: [chats: {c, messages: y}]
  )
)
```

```

Comment: Would not `join: (y in assoc(c, :messages)) |> limit(1)` work?

Answer (score 0):

```
defmacro last_message_id(chat_id) do
  quote do
    fragment("""
      (
        SELECT
          m.ID
        FROM
          MESSAGES m
        WHERE
          m.CHAT_ID = ?
        ORDER BY m.INSERTED_AT ASC
        LIMIT 1
      )
    """, unquote(chat_id))
  end
end

post = Repo.get(Post, id)

chats_with_last_message =
  post
  |> assoc(:chats)
  |> join(:inner, [c], m in Message, m.id == last_message_id(c.id)
  |> select([c, m], %{chat: c, message: m})
  |> Repo.all()
```

Okay, that should get you started. I used two queries here but it's possible to put it into one using [this](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#preload/3-preload-queries). Also pay attention to the `INNER` join, which means that it filters the chats to those that have at least one message.

PS I have not tested the code but even if it doesn't work, you get the idea. Somebody who has more time will probably post a proper answer.